# Connecting to MongoDB Atlas from firebase functions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-functions, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect to mongodb atlas from firebase functions like.

```
export default async () => {
  try {
    const url = 'mongodb+srv://foo:bar@foo-cluster.mongodb.net/my-db?retryWrites=true';
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    client.dbName('my-db');
    return client;
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

However, I am getting this error:

> {
>       "code": "ESERVFAIL",
>       "errno": "ESERVFAIL",
>       "syscall": "querySrv",
>       "hostname": "_mongodb._tcp.foo-cluster.mongodb.net"
>   }

1. I made sure that my firebase plan is set to Blaze so I can connect to any client outside of google network.
2. I whitelisted the functions' IP in mongodb atlas dashboard, I also added "connect from everywhere" just to make sure.
3. I am using nodejs mongo driver version `^3.1.0-beta4`

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a "beta" driver. Also the connection string is not for you. You almost certainly don't want the `retryWrites` option, and you probably don't want the `my-db` on the end if you used the Atlas console to create users, because they should be in the default "admin" database. Also `client.db('my-db')` ( which is another correction ) does not "persist". You want to return the `client` instance and select the "database" in different code. The error itself seems more indicative of a communication problem. Probably because you have not added the remote host to the whitelist.

Comment: Just realized that `3.1.0-beta4` is actually marked as `stable` on `npm`. It shouldn't be. Please also make sure you install `3.0.8` explicitly until somebody fixes that.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for the pointers.

Comment: @NeilLunn can you suggest of a better way to export the db instance after the successfull connection?

Comment: You probably should not. Exporting the `client` context is better and then you simply select the `.db()` from that. It's not really an "instance" anyhow, as nothing communicates with the server after connection until you call a collection method, or something else that does something.

Comment: @NeilLunn Right! Thanks, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 8):

There are few caveats when connecting to Atlas from Firebase Function. Below is the correct way to return a connected client instance for further use in your FB function:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

const uri = 'mongodb://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@foo-shard-00-00-xxx.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,foo-shard-00-01-xxx.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,foo-shard-00-02-xxx.gcp.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=FOO-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true'

let client

export default async () => {

    if (client && client.isConnected()) {
        console.log('DB CLIENT ALREADY CONNECTED')

    } else try {
        client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true })
        console.log('DB CLIENT RECONNECTED')
    }

    catch (e) {
    throw e
    }

    return client
}
```

**Explanation:**

1. reportedly, you cannot connect to Atlas if you are on a *Spark* plan. Make sure you upgrade to Blaze if you didn't yet.
2. `uri` string – You should not use the shortened url format when connecting to Atlas from Firebase. For some reason, only the older, long url format works reliably from firebase.
3. `client` variable – You should define the `client` variable outside the export scope, and then assign the connected client instance to it inside the function, only if it is not already assigned. This will prevent reconnecting the client on every function invocation. Firebase functions are *stateless*, but not entirely. they only get shut down after some period of inactivity. This means that the connection will persist for some time. [From docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#use_dependencies_wisely): If you declare a variable in global scope, its value can be reused in subsequent invocations without having to be recomputed.

Comment: Update. You don't have to upgrade from the spark plan to do this, you just have to configure a GCP billing account to use with your Firebase project

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the network access rules of my mongodb atlas cluster didn't allow firebase function to access the database. I had to allow access from anywhere to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, i did:

- Enable Billing for your project, it will automatically enable the Outbound Network Requests for your app.

Outbound Networks Requests are free up to 5gb/month. So just enable billing and enjoy.

More info about billing here.
https://firebase.google.com/pricing#blaze-calculator

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but note the original question states "I made sure that my firebase plan is set to Blaze so I can connect to any client outside of google network."