# How to connect to MongoDb Atlas from firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-functions, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50362647/connecting-to-mongodb-atlas-from-firebase-functions) answer to connect to a mongodb atlas db from cloud functions.

I use this code from the answer above:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

const uri = 'mongodb://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@foo-shard-00-00-xxx.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,foo-shard-00-01-xxx.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,foo-shard-00-02-xxx.gcp.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=FOO-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true'

let client

export default async () => {

    if (client && client.isConnected()) {
        console.log('DB CLIENT ALREADY CONNECTED')

    } else try {
        client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true })
        console.log('DB CLIENT RECONNECTED')
    }

    catch (e) {
    throw e
    }

    return client
}
```

And then I have a function like this:

```
export const myFunction = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onRequest((request, response) => {
console.log(client.isConnected());
});
```

When I run `firebase serve` locally, I don't see 'DB CLIENT ALREADY CONNECTED' or  'DB CLIENT RECONNECTED' which means that anonymous function didn't get called. And when I try to access the `client` variable inside `myFunction` I get an error.

I'm learning Node at the moment so this might be a simple question. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you have some code to run in Cloud Functions, you need to invoke it.  It's not possible to simply declare or export some function and expect it to run without calling it.  If you want something to run at the global scope of your code, either don't wrap it in a function, or call the function at the global scope.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I realize that the question is not very smart. I'm not sure how to call that function that connects to the db. This might be more of a Node question.

Comment: I'm curious why you declared it "export default".  Could you just give it a regular name and invoke it like any other JavaScript function?

Comment: I did try to declare it as a regular function like `connect = async () => {//do connection}` and call it in side `myFunction`. Then when I run `firebase serve` and call `myFunction` multiple times, it creates a new connection every time the function is called.

Comment: That's a completely different problem, and also the way you can expect the emulator to work.  It currently restarts everything for every invocation.  If you would like a different behavior for the emulator, please file an issue on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know thats how the emulator works. I deployed a function and tested it multiple times and it maintained the connection. all is good thank you Doug :).